# Data is not being written in my .dat file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char rationno[10];
char price[10];
char riceq[10] = {'4', '0', '0', '\0'};
char pulseq[10];
char petrolq[10];
char no[10];
void ration();

int main()
{
    ration();
}

void ration()
{
    int f = 0;
    cout << "Enter ration card no.: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cin >> no[i];
        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter ration card no.: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    if (strlen(no) == 4)
    {
        f = 1;
        cout << "Access Granted!!" << endl;

        cout << "You will get this much rice petrol and pulses" << endl;

        ofstream rq;
        rq.open("rice.dat", ios::binary | ios::in |ios::out);
        int newr = atoi(riceq); //changes char array to integer
        rq << no << ";" << endl;
        rq << "Current quantity: " << newr << ";" << endl;
        newr -= 20;
        rq << "Updated quantity is: " << newr << ";" << endl;
        rq.close();

        cout << "Updated stock is: " << newr;
    }

    else
    {
        f = 0;
        cout << "Access Denied!! try again" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have created `rice.dat` file using notepad but when I open it, it is always empty. The code is just working fine but it is not able to write anything in the file. This code is actually working the VS but I do not know what is going wrong when I try to create the file using notepad.

Comment: You should make operator overloading function for writing value in file.use this ofstream rq.open("rice.dat", ios::app);

Comment: Does your code successfully open the file? Is it the same file that you're looking at in notepad? (i.e., are you looking in the folder, since you don't specify a path in your code so it will be in whatever default folder your program has when it runs)

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.